# Some hard drives not detected when starting or restarting a computer

Tags: linux, windows, boot, grub, dualboot

I have a dual boot of Manjaro and Windows 10. Each OS is on its own hard disk and my default hard disk too boot from is the one with Manjaro. There is strange behaviour when I want to log on to my Windows OS when restarting or turning on the PC for the first time, when I select Windows in GRUB menu it displays a message that the hard disk couldnt be found. I then need to restart again and enter the boot settings and just open the boot priority menu (not changing anything just open it). Then I exit the boot menu and when starting Windows from GRUB it works normaly.

It seems like when opening boot menu via F2 the SATA ports get scanned and all hard disks are recognised. I dont know what additional info I could post to resolve this so please mention them and I will edit the question

Answer (score 0):

MS Windows cannot boot from every partition from every disk. There are restrictions. Fortunately, GRUB2 can boot nearly everything. I suggest to consult the documentation related to GRUB2 and to build an appropriate GRUB2 config. Be sure, GRUB2 will be started at first.